# Split the String extracted from json extractor in Jmeter with sets of n

Tags: json, split, jmeter

I have a scenario in which an API responds with a value occurring more than 1000 times and i capture it using Json extractor with ${variable}_all.

I need to split it into sets of 50 or less and parametrise those sets of 50 multiple times  into the next API call.

Is there any way to accomplish this ?

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1**

You need to slice the values from the JSON Response. You can use [JSON JMSEPath Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_JMESPath_Extractor) to slice the first fifty. values from the large number of values.

[List and Slice Projections](https://jmespath.org/tutorial.html#list-and-slice-projections)

**Solution 2**
If you want to work with the concatenated result following example could be useful.

```
def values_ALL = vars.get("<variable name>_ALL")
def filteredValues = values_ALL.split(",")[0..50]

for (i in 0..<filteredValues.size()) {
    println(filteredValues[i])
}
```

Note : JMeter variable names are case sensitive

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [Loop Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Loop_Controller) and use the following __groovy() function as the "Loop Count"

   ```
   ${__groovy(vars.get('variable_ALL') as int / 50,)}
   ```
2. Inside the Loop Controller you can use [JSR223 PreProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PreProcessor) to generate the request body and refer each "chunk" of the variables like:

   ```
   def offset = (vars.get('__jm__Loop Controller__idx')) as int * 50

   def payload = new StringBuilder()

   offset.upto((offset + 50), { index ->
       payload.append(vars.get('variable_' + index)).append(System.getProperty('line.separator'))
   })

   sampler.addNonEncodedArgument('', payload.toString(),  '')
   sampler.setPostBodyRaw(true)
   ```

More information on Groovy scripting in JMeter: [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black)

If you need to produce JSON payload you may find [Parsing and producing JSON](https://groovy-lang.org/json.html) article interesting as well